# Simple call VS Invoke in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Can you explain the distinction between directly calling a passed method and utilizing the invoke function?

```
    private fun mFun(mMethod: (String) -> Unit){
    mMethod("Name")
    mMethod.invoke("NAme")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in your example.

But if your function property were nullable, you would need `invoke` to be able to do a null-safe invocation of the function:

```
private fun mFun(maybeNullFunc: ((String) -> Unit)?) {
    maybeNullFunc?.invoke("NAme")
}
```

Side notes:

- `mMethod` is improper use of Hungarian notation. `m` as a prefix means "member", which a function property is not. In Kotlin, member references are properties. Most programmers do not use Hungarian notation, by the way.
- "method" is a misleading name for your parameter. It's a function, but not necessarily a method. A method is a function that is a member of a class.

For example: here I'm calling your function with a method of String:

```
mFun(String::length)
```

but here I'm not:

```
mFun { println(it.length) }
```

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd invoke method allow you to call the function of a class as if they were a function inside your class or scope, and not on the other class. Theres no difference between them, to use both of them you still need to create an instance of the class.